# How can I stream audio using Socket.io in real time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, socket.io, streaming

I am currently using socket.io to create a chat application in HTML and JS. I am able to communication between two computers easily sending written messages. My problem is that I am not able to figure out how to send real-time voice recorded in one computer to the other. I am using "navigator.getUserMedia" to record audio from the microphone and it works great, but I can not send it to through Socket.io to another computer.

I know that I can start recording, then stop and finally send the result, but it is not what I need, what I need is real-time streaming.

This is the code for the server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var path = require('path');
var users = [];

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

socket.on('add user', function(user_id){
    users.push(user_id);
});

socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
});
socket.on('voice sent', function(msg){
    io.emit('voice received', msg);
});
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

And this is client js:

```
$(function () {
    var socket = io();
    var user_id = Math.random();

    socket.emit('add user', user_id);

    $('form').submit(function(){
      socket.emit('chat message', {"message": $('#m').val(), "user": user_id});
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      if(msg.user == user_id){
        $('#messages').append($('<li class="mine">').text(msg.message));
      }
      else{
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg.message));
      }

    });

    socket.on('voice received', function(msg){
      var audio = document.querySelector('audio'); 
      audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    });

    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                     navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                     navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
       console.log('getUserMedia supported.');
       navigator.getUserMedia ({audio: true}, successCallback, errorCallback);
    } else {
       console.log('getUserMedia not supported on your browser!');
    }

    function successCallback(stream){
       socket.emit('voice sent', stream);
    }

    function errorCallback(error) {
      console.error('An error occurred: [CODE ' + error.code + ']');
    }
  });
```

I hope somebody can help me. Thanks

Comment: You can use webRTC, have a look over document it will help you.

Comment: to send or receive audio requires the act of recording and rendering the audio ... in your efforts I would put in place code to handle those responsibilities before you venture onward to sending binary data across the wire ... I have used sockets to send audio however that is the easy part in my opinion ... there is a reason why it took 15 years before the web had streaming audio

Comment: Thank you so much @PandhiBhaumik, I finally find a solution for this. It works great.

Comment: What you've used?

Comment: I used Simple-Peer and GetUserMedia: https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-peer && https://www.npmjs.com/package/getusermedia When I finished the project I will upload to github and share the link ;)

Answer (score 2):

I tried to do so , after a while i done it so :

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      audioCtx: new AudioContext(), // for get stream from mic and send via socket
      audioC: new AudioContext(), // for receive data from socket and translate and play 
    }
  },
  created() {
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia

    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
      console.log('getUserMedia supported.')

      navigator.getUserMedia(
        { audio: true },
        stream => {
          const source = this.audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream)
          const processor = this.audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1)

          source.connect(processor)
          processor.connect(this.audioCtx.destination)

          processor.onaudioprocess = e => {
            this.$store.state.mic.Emit('Voice', e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0))
          }

          this.$store.state.mic.On('Voice', msg => {
            const fbu = new Float32Array(Object.values(JSON.parse(msg)))
            const audioBuffer = this.audioC.createBuffer(1, 2048, this.audioC.sampleRate)

            audioBuffer.getChannelData(0).set(fbu)

            const sourceNode = new AudioBufferSourceNode(this.audioC, { buffer: audioBuffer })

            sourceNode.connect(this.audioC.destination)
            sourceNode.start(0)
          })

          this.audioC.resume()
        },
        err => console.error(err)
      )
    }
  }
}
```

and the server just sends every thing it got to all except sender client
but still there is problem , due to different AudioBufferSourceNode the call quality is not good , it's separated and chopped.

Comment: yes, by changing the baud rate and decreasing the voice quality it solved.

Comment: onaudioprocess is deprecated!!

Answer (score 1):

in this block of code

```
    socket.on('voice received', function(msg){
      var audio = document.querySelector('audio'); 
      audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    });
```

stream is defined nowhere ....
i think this could solve your problem

```
    socket.on('voice received', function(msg){
      var audio = document.querySelector('audio'); 
      audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(msg);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use peer or webrtc.. lot of live examples available in git...

FYI
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/building-a-video-chat-app-with-node-js-socket-io-webrtc-26f46b213017

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).